# Tensorflow import error: module 'imp' has no attribute 'find_module'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to import tensorflow (I have installed on 14.04 LTS and tensorflow 0.8) but it shows

```
 atributeError: module 'imp' has no attribute 'find_module'

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/prayalankar/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/prayalankar/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/prayalankar/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/prayalankar/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(\__file__)])
AttributeError: module 'imp' has no attribute 'find_module'
```

How to proceed?

Comment: How did you install it? Pls write in detailes. Perhaps there're some errors during installation?

Comment: i installed using anaconda  . First i created a new environment in anaconda . Downloaded the https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
and changed cp34-cp34m to py3 after reading the issues from tensorflow github . Then it was installed . It gave  error  "No Flask " i resolved that after which it is giving above error

Comment: Publish all installation log.

Comment: BTW, Python 3 support is not as well tested as Python 2, you could try getting it working with Python 2.7 first

Comment: Thanks  @Yaroslav Bulatov I installed tensorflow i python 2.x using conda environment after your comment and I am ready to go in 15 minutes . thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems that I had a `imp.py` in home directory which was confusing the imp of python so I had to change the name of `imp.py`