# AttributeError:module 'imp' has no attribute 'find_module'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used this code to import in VSCODE editor.
Getting error as below.
Already installed tensorflow by `pip install tensorflow` in command line.
Any help please?

```
import tensorflow  

File "C:\Users\david\python3_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
AttributeError: module 'imp' has no attribute 'find_module'
```

Comment: how did you install tensorflow. Did you build it yourself from source?

Comment: used   'pip install tensorflow' in cmd.

Comment: do you have any other file named imp.py in your machine

Comment: changed to imp1.py. still same issue.

Comment: which file did you change to imp1.py? Are there any other files named imp.py?

Comment: imp.py to imp1.py.  no more files called imp.py.

Comment: in this folder "C\users\david\python3_6\lib\site_packages"

Comment: Make sure you have no other imp.py files inside the directory it could cause confusion I believe. Also heres this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278779/attributeerrormodule-imp-has-no-attribute-find-module

Answer (score 3):

I had such kind of problem, when my working directory contained custom file with the same name ("imp.py"). Perhaps, your project also contains such file :)
Just find and open file that throws an error and then Ctrl+click on "imp" module to open it in separate tab to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you used

```
pip install tensorflow
```

It would most likely install packages corresponding to ***python2***

To install for ***python3*** as your directory suggests, use

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

Also checkout this answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37674563/5668215

If it still persists, uninstall or purge the present tensorflow installation using `pip` and reinstall it using `pip3`